# Rotating image also stretches or shrinks on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, rotation

I try to rotate my image :

```
UIImageView *image;
image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0175*degrees);
// 0.0175 = pi/180 = 1 degree in radians
```

if e.g

```
degrees = 90*x // x = 1,2,3,4
```

it's alright, but when `degrees = 45` the image suddenly becomes really thin, and in other case it also stretches or shrinks. 
What can be the cause of this?

I have also tried

```
CGAffineTransform transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(image.transform, degrees);
image.transform = transform;
```

with similar results.

EDIT: I have also tried with `image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;` but then it gets to big

Comment: Dont use the transform.image it generally changes the dimensions of the image while rotating or zooming .... Can you provide the code in full instead of patches ?

Comment: The first code snippet is actually the full code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set bounds and center? Try  like this, but with your metrics:

```
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 200);
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(myrectr.origin.x + (bounds.size.width / 2.0f),
    imageViewRect.origin.y + (bounds.size.height / 2.0f) + 100.0f);

    [imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];

    [imageView setCenter:center];
    [imageView setBounds:bounds];

    [imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 4.0f)];
```

Comment: still i am getting the problem... is there any other option to do..PLease help me @Tutankhamen